# Virtual hosts and www redirects causing infinate redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, virtualhost

Hi I have two virtual hosts and I am trying to redirect non www to www without using the RewriteEngine, it works just fine if I only add the redirect to one of them, but when I add it to both the sites it causes an infinite redirect.

Please I want to do this without RewriteEngine.

Also I'm doing this in the Apache config file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.site1.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias site2.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.site2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing virtualhost that catches www subdomain that may cause infinite redirect. Try this:

```
//Redirect non-www to www
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.site1.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

and then set up another `<VirtualHost>` section with `ServerName www.site1.com` so it catches www one.